# Scripting. How to declare and work with vectors that define the centers of cubes?

Tags: python, scripting

I am learning python for Blender and having some difficulties so I humbly request some help. I am trying to replicate the ¨Recursion in all directions¨ script [found here](http://koaning.io/python-cubes-in-blender.html), but doing it my way, I try to preserve the sets of cube centers for all the iterations to extend the script with other features I want to learn. However I am having problems with my code:

```
import bpy
import math
n=4 #write here the desired number of iterations (the first iteration is the first cube))
def distance(p):
    return 3/(p+1) #the function defining the distance between cubes
def radius(p):
    return 1/math.log(p+2) #function defining the radius of the cubes. We now define the centers of the cubes for each iteration 
listOfCenterSets = [[] for i in range(n)]
listOfCenterSets[0].append((0,0,0)) #the center, here the action starts
for i in range(n):
    for c in listOfCenterSets[i]:
        listOfCenterSets[i+1].append(c+(1,0,0)*distance(i))
        listOfCenterSets[i+1].append(c+(0,1,0)*distance(i))
        listOfCenterSets[i+1].append(c+(0,0,1)*distance(i))
        listOfCenterSets[i+1].append(c+(-1,0,0)*distance(i))
        listOfCenterSets[i+1].append(c+(0,-1,0)*distance(i))
        listOfCenterSets[i+1].append(c+(0,0,-1)*distance(i)) #we now add the cubes
for i in range (n):
    for c in listOfCenterSets[i]:
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(location=c, radius=radius(i))
```

I believe the problem is with me not understanding how to declare and work with the vectors that define the centers of the cubes.

Thank you.

Comment: (among other things) you can't multiply a python sequence (eg (0, 1, 0)) by a float.  Make it a mathutils.Vector   `d * Vector((0, 1, 0))` where d is a scalar.